# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error ORA-06512: " while executing code

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
for i in (select * from order_dtls order by 1 asc) loop

    select b.dealer_id
      into n_dealer
      from booking_mst b
     where b.booking_id = i.booking_id;

    dbms_output.put_line(n_cnt ||'--'|| to_char(sysdate,'yyyymmdd') ||'--'|| chr(1) || '43' ||'--'||
                         chr(1) || n_dealer ||'--'|| '1525' ||'--'|| '0' ||'--'|| i.amount ||'--'||
                         chr(1) || i.product_id ||'--'|| chr(1) || i.quantity ||'--'||
                         chr(1) || to_char(i.order_date,'yyyymmdd') + 1 ||'--'|| chr(1) ||
                         to_char(i.order_date,'yyyymmdd'));

    commit;

    n_cnt := n_cnt + 1;

  end loop;
```

Comment: `to_char(i.order_date,'yyyymmdd') + 1` ... I don't know if this is legitimate, or using `n_cnt` as a character string.

Comment: It would be fine if you would post a minimal example that fails and not your full code.

Comment: I think `to_char(i.order_date,'yyyymmdd') + 1` is wrong. For example 31st of May will return 20170532, i.e. "32nd of May" - which does not exist. It should be `to_char(i.order_date+1,'yyyymmdd')` I assume.

Comment: This is just a piece of code with an error message. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  If I went up to a colleague and slapped a printout of a code fragment with an error message on his desk with no other comment or information do you think I would get an answer ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

```
. . . || to_char(i.order_date,'yyyymmdd') + 1  ||
```

Which is currently seen as:

```
(. . . || to_char(i.order_date,'yyyymmdd')) + 1  ||
```

The implicit number conversion fails for the above and hence the error.

Enclose the addition `to_char(i.order_date,'yyyymmdd') + 1` inside parentheses:

```
dbms_output.put_line(n_cnt ||'--'|| to_char(sysdate,'yyyymmdd') ||'--'|| chr(1) || '43' ||'--'||
                     chr(1) || n_dealer ||'--'|| '1525' ||'--'|| '0' ||'--'|| i.amount ||'--'||
                     chr(1) || i.product_id ||'--'|| chr(1) || i.quantity ||'--'||
                     chr(1) || (to_char(i.order_date,'yyyymmdd') + 1) ||'--'|| chr(1) ||
                     to_char(i.order_date,'yyyymmdd'));
```

#### EDIT:

As noted by Wernfried, there is another problem in your code. You should add 1 to the date, not the result string.

So correct code will be:

inside parentheses:

```
dbms_output.put_line(n_cnt ||'--'|| to_char(sysdate,'yyyymmdd') ||'--'|| chr(1) || '43' ||'--'||
                     chr(1) || n_dealer ||'--'|| '1525' ||'--'|| '0' ||'--'|| i.amount ||'--'||
                     chr(1) || i.product_id ||'--'|| chr(1) || i.quantity ||'--'||
                     chr(1) || to_char(i.order_date + 1,'yyyymmdd') ||'--'|| chr(1) ||
                     to_char(i.order_date,'yyyymmdd'));
```